# How to hide certain html that is not surrounded by <noscript> tags if javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, graceful-degradation

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         // jquery and javascript functions
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <fancy-jquery-ajaxy-html-section>
        </fancy-jquery-ajaxy-html-section>

        <noscript>
        sorry you came to the wrong place - this site is all jquery/ajaxy stuff.
        </noscript>

    </body>

</html>
```

I tried surrounding `<fancy-jquery-ajaxy-html>` with a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` but then **nothing from that section is displayed even for users with javascript enabled**.

But what I want to do is hide that `<fancy-jquery-ajax-html>` section **only if the user doesn't have javascript enabled**.

It contains content that is useless to someone without javascript turned on, so it shouldn't be shown at all.

A user with javascript disabled should **only** see a message saying that the page can't be viewed without javascript.

Is there a way do that?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to hide the section with CSS (e.g. `display:none`), then show it through Javascript.

EDIT: just a little example

```
<div>Everyone sees this div</div>

<div id="mydiv" class="hidden">You see this div only with JS enabled</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mydiv").removeClass("hidden");
</script>
<noscript>
    <div>You will see this div only with JS disabled</div>
</noscript>
```

And, of course, in your CSS:

```
.hidden
  {
  display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could hide your fancy section using css:

```
<div id="fancy_jquery_ajax" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

then you could use use JavaScript to display the element:

```
$("#fancy_jquery_ajax").css("display", "block");
```

I hope that's right, I actually don't use jQuery that much. :S

Comment: That's right (the jQuery), but it would be more readable to use, say `.show()` instead of `.css()`.

Comment: Ah yes, that would definitely be better.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to generate that HTML using JavaScript, so it can't appear unless JavaScript is running.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to have my javascript hide the `nojsdiv` and show `maindiv`.  This way, if you don't have javascript the message shows up.

```
<body onload="allowlogin()">
    <div id="maindiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
...
    </div>
    <div id="nojsdiv">
        The training system requires javascript to be enabled.
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add a class of `.js` to html tags as soon as jQuery has loaded. This allows my to write css rules that apply only when the user has javascript enabled/disabled. This keeps your show and hide code out of our JS and lets CSS do its job and style the page

Here's how I would approach your problem:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .js #fancy_jquery_ajax {display: none;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('html').addClass('js');
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready
      });  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id = "fancy_jquery_ajax"></div>
      <noscript><!-- stuff to say if use had javascript disabled --></noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's important to note that we want to add the class of `.js` as *soon as jQuery has loaded* and not add it in our `document.ready` handler. Otherwise we'd be back to square one.